# Using attributes from a raised Exception in another file

Tags: python, xbee

I have a script that uses the digi.xbee.devices library.

The script receives data from another xbee(radio) device and outputs it to the terminal. The script that does this is called **main.py**

My issue/question is:

Sometimes I receive a malformed packet and an exception is raised in another file (one of the library files we will call it **file2.py**).

The exception:

```
                    except InvalidPacketException as e:
                        self._log.error("Error processing packet")
                        continue
```

This simply produces the string "Error processing packet" in my terminal.

**Is there a way I can access this exception when it triggers?** I want to perform something specific when its hits without modifying the library file that raises the exception.

I was hoping I could access whatever the self._log.error is and just search to see if it contains the word "Error".

Comment: _log seems like a Logger of the logging module. It's main purpose is, as the name states, to log events and usually does not acts as an "error handler" lets say. You could in fact constantly check the file _log is logging to, but I don't think it's a good idea. The way to do it (I know you don't want to) is to modify file2.py and whether to re-raise the exception, in case you can later catch it, or put it on a queue and read that same queue on your script.

Comment: Thank you, I went ahead and just modified the library file and added my code in its exception block. I will just have to remember this (I will comment it in).